# What to expect from an e-bike service?

Tags: maintenance, electric-bike

My e-bike manufacturer recommends a service every 1000km. Tomorrow I'll bring my bike to the shop where I bought it for the first service. I already had a mini-service for free at around 300 km in which I don't know what they did exactly, probably some fine screw tuning.

My bike is a city bike built by a reputable manufacturer. I ride it nearly everyday to work. The city has some serious hills.

What can I expect the shop where I'll bring my e-bike will be doing for this ~1000km service? (And will it be the same for every 1000km services in the future?)

Comment: An EBike, big hills and I presume every day commuting means some wet weather days, I would not be surprised if you need a new chain.

Comment: Service intervals of 1000km look rather short. Especially if you do some routine checks regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list from the service I got from my local store

- Perform drivetrain inspection including chain ring nut tension
- Clean front chainring area
- Check bearing operation
- Check motor mounting bolts
- Perform gear tune up
- Perform brake inspection
- Check spoke tension
- Check suspension operation
- Lubricate chain
- Check and test operation of all sensors
- Check battery mounting
- Visually check wiring harness
- Clean speed sensor and check tension
- Plug in diagnostic tool
- Check system for errors
- Check system for software updates
- Print report
- Inspect all critical components
- Check and adjust tire pressures

Your store may have a different procedure but that sounds typical for any ebike service. If you know how to do some maintenance yourself like cleaning and lubing the chain as well as replacing it when it gets worn you shouldn't need to take it in for a service every 1000km. Every 4000km is closer to how often I would do it.

Answer (score 7):

The first free service is usually just to account for "bedding-in" from new. They originally build up and tune the bike with all new components, but as you ride it for a few months, it's common for cables to bed in a little more snugly to their fittings as well as for bearings to push into the frame a little more, requiring the components on either side to be tightened up. The bolts on the bike may be a little loose from all of this, so it's always a good idea to get it fully checked over once it's been ridden for a while.

After 1000 km, it would be checked over for all of that as well as for the general wear and tear. Components requiring cleaning and lubricration will be inspected along with any bearings. Depending on motor position, ebikes might wear out a drivetrain more quickly or require wheels to be trued more often. If you know how to clean and lubricate your bike and measure the chain wear, it's unlikely to need such regular maintenance, but the recommendations tend to be based on the worst case scenario. Someone who rides in all weather, locking it up outside during the day and just puts the bike back in the garage every evening without cleaning it can extensive maintenance within 1000 km.

To minimise maintenance required, there are some basic things to do at home. If the bike gets dirty, clean it off, taking care not to leave it soaking wet for a long time afterwards. Regularly (every 300km or so) degrease and relubricate your chain and pump up your tyres to the correct pressure. An honest bike shop will usually take a look at a bike to tell you whether any more work is required at the time. Unfortunately it can be hard to know how honest your shop is of you aren't an expert, so you should ask your friends for their opinions on the local shops

Answer (score 3):

Most bike shops offer several levels of service depending on what you instruct them to do.

For example:

- Basic: Check tyres, brakes, adjust gears
- Intermediate: Basic + check/true wheels
- Advanced: As intermediate + check/re-grease all bearings as appropriate

In addition there can be extra 'add on' services such as bleeding hydraulic brake systems and servicing suspension components.

Answer (score 2):

Most bike shops offer different maintenance services and list what each service entails.

After 1000km there shouldn’t be any major wear&tear so no replacements (chain, battery, brake pads etc.) should be necessary.

I guess they’ll

- Check/tighten all bolts with a torque wrench
- Adjust shifting cable tension if necessary
- Adjust (mechanical) brakes if necessary
- Check spoke tension and wheel trueness and true it if necessary.
- Clean and lube the chain if necessary
- Check for bearing play and adjust if necessary
- Check for obvious damage

If the bike was properly built initially there shouldn’t be anything wrong after "only" 1000km. If this service is expensive I wouldn’t do it. It’s mostly just a check if anything’s gone out of adjustment.

After 2000 to 3000km you’ll need a new chain and possibly brake pads. After 6000km you’ll need your third chain and cassette and it’s probably a good idea to replace cables&cable housing.

Comment: We don't know what type of e-bike the OP has.  If its an e-mtb it could easily need new chain and brake pads after 1000km

Comment: @AndyP Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the question to describe the bike and the use case.